# Regex that allows special chars?

Tags: c#, regex

The below regex requires that the password has 1 number, 1 char (upper or lower) and is a minimum of 8 in length.  But if I type in a special char it returns false.  I don't want to require a special char, but i want to allow it in this context. How can I alter this regex to allow a special char?

```
Regex.IsMatch(Password, "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])\w{8,}$")
```

Comment: any special character?  Please specify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing "\w" to "." should do it:

```
Regex.IsMatch(Password, "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$")
```

\w matches "word" characters, which won't normally match special characters (depending on your definition of "special" and the language you're using).
. will match any character except newline

Comment: "Special character" usually means punctuation, or maybe punctuation and whitespace. It's from the same geekspeak dialect that calls digits "numbers" and letters, "characters".

Answer (score 4):

```
Regex.IsMatch(Password, "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$")
```

Comment: This permits spaces in the password. I suspect that is not desired.

Comment: Why would spaces be any less desirable in a password than, say, ampersands?

Comment: Good point. But you'd likely want to trim/restrict leading & trailing whitespace.

Comment: Still not really feeling it.  What's the theory there, that if someone has a space at the beginning or end of their password, they must have typoed?  That's what password confirmations are for.

Comment: I'd go so far as to say that it's *important* to support spaces in a password, because people normally don't think of them as usable, which means they inherently increase password strength more than other characters.

Comment: You're following the DAMN principle. Developer As every MaN. Yes, you and I would probably utilize spaces at the beginning or end of a password. However, the vast majority of computer users are <insert P.C. synonym for clueless>. Users may be copy/pasting their password from a file, which may include an errant space. I agree with permitting whitespace within a password. Yet there are valid arguments against permitting leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: Ahh, there we go.  That was what I was looking for: a valid argument. :)  I wouldn't always be guided by that one, but it's definitely worth thinking about.  +1 for your answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

Why not do 3 separate checks, that way you can clearly check if the password meets the required parameters but without having to maintain a large Regex?

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(Password, "\d") &&
    Regex.IsMatch(Password, "\w") &&
    Password.length >= 8) //psuedo-code
```

This won't restrict any characters.  It checks that the password has at least one word character, at least one number, and is at least 8 characters long.

Comment: Doesn't match special chars though.

Comment: Doesn't match them, but doesn't need to.  It doesn't *exclude* them either.  Of course, the plusses are superfluous.

Comment: nice, however I wourd refactor Regex.IsMatch(Password, "\d") into a method called "ContainsAtLeastOneWordCharector()" etc so as it make it clear what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

Toran, if you do not want to permit whitespace in your password use the following:

```
Regex.IsMatch(Password, "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]\S{8,}$")
```